# Email Sendpreview Invalid Recipient

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have DataExtension and an email, when I try sendpreview I can see all emails as Invalid Recipient.

I have no idea why these emails are Invalid?

Comment: You will receive this error if the subscriber records is not in all subscribers.   If the subscriber has never been sent an email, then they may not exist in all_subscribers.

Comment: DE based on SFDC report, if I create a new report it works fine. Problem is only with that particular DE.

Answer (score 1):

This error generally appears if Data extenssion has some other attribute other than email address as primary key and there are more than one field of type Email Address.

On trying to click preview, system will not be able to determine the Email address to be displayed. To resolve the issue, you should make one of the email address column of type Text. Else your subsciber list should be updated with the subscriber key and email address.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest Solution is to run the email through validation against the data extension.  The validator will provide some more insights into why it is throwing an error. ([walkthrough for classic content editor](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/validate_an_email/)) Below is a sample image of where to find the validate tool in Content Builder.

[image]

If the validator runs with no errors, you should start looking into your script and see if you have any if statements that are 'run only at X environment' ([usually based on messagecontext or isTestSend)](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/personalization_strings/strings/).  This is likely where your issue would be.

Comment: Validated without any error

Comment: If that is the case I would contact support. It may be an issue with the UI or something beyond our control

Comment: If you provide more information - perhaps a sample of the HTML or DE data, we can assist further. If you talked with support and received an explanation or solution, please be sure to share here as well to assist those that may experience the same issues.